# how to generate a log in kubectl pod by command line

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, kubectl

I have a mysqldb pod and need to add a log when we run a script restorebackup.sh. The script is inside the pod and i need this log in the general logs of the pod (to access it with kubectl get logs services/mysqldb).

There is any way to do this?

Comment: it depends on the pod, but assuming PID 1 is the `command:` that's currently having its output go to stdout, then `echo "hello from my shell script" >/proc/1/fd/1` may do it, depending on a lot of factors

Answer (score 10):

Generally the `kubectl logs` shows the first process's stdout (pid=1).
So you could try put logs to /proc/1/fd/1 in you pod.

An example command in pod:

```
echo hello >> /proc/1/fd/1
```

Then you will able to see this `hello` by `kubectl logs`.

For you script `restorebackup.sh`, maybe you could try `sh restorebackup.sh >> /proc/1/fd/1` to redirect all outputs.

Comment: now I'm having a problem with permissions. proc/1 has mysql permission instead of root.  And I cannot change the permissions of this to root :(

Comment: As you are root, does it possible to run the scripts with mysql user by `su -c`?

Answer (score 2):

- kubectl logs is nothing but the stdout&stderr stream of the container (pid 1 process) in it
- So to have restorebackup.sh output saved to a file and also to stream it to stdout , we can use utilities like tee ( it saves output to a file and also to stdout)

Example :

```
[root@c3~]# echo foo | tee boo
foo
[root@c3~]# cat boo
foo
```

- in your case `restorebackup.sh` should be modified in such a way that all the output generating commands should use `tee`

Answer (score 1):

> A container engine handles and redirects any output generated to a containerized application's `stdout` and `stderr` streams.

> On Linux, the set of file descriptors open in a process can be accessed under the path `/proc/PID/fd/`, where `PID` is the process identifier. File descriptor `/proc/PID/fd/0` is `stdin`, `/proc/PID/fd/1` is `stdout`, and `/proc/PID/fd/2` is `stderr`.

So, assuming the main command in a container has PID '1' run the following command inside a k8s Pod:

```
$ sh restorebackup.sh >> /proc/1/fd/1
```

Then you will see its `stdout` in the Pod's logs.

```
$ kubectl logs yourPodName
...
some stdout from your script...
...
```

Keep in mind, that this way you only write the `stdout` of your bash script.

To write **stdout and stderr** from your script, run it like this:

```
$ sh restorebackup.sh 1>> /proc/1/fd/1 2>> /proc/1/fd/2
```

Or modify the code of the script to write info messages to `/proc/1/fd/1` and error messages to `/proc/1/fd/2`.

Comment: yeah, but i'm having an error because fd/1 has mysql permissions instead of root. I've tried use su -c but it's still not working :(

command:
su mysql -c "echo hello >> /proc/1/fd/1"

message:
cannot create /proc/1/fd/1: Permission denied

Comment: @Vitor Estevam, which container image do you use?

Comment: @Vitor Estevam try runuser -l mysql -c 'command'